# Show each object from NSMutableDictionary in log

Tags: iphone, xcode

Here's a bit of a newbie question.

I have a NSMutableDictionary *dict

which in the log looks like this:

```
"test1" = "5";
"test2" = "78";
"test3" = "343";
"test4" = "3";
```

I need to print each number by itself, but I'm pretty poor at arrays and FOR-sentences.

I was thinking something like:

```
    for (dict) {
    double number = [[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"Number: %f",number); 

}
```

Which I want to look like this in the log on each line:

```
Number: 5
Number: 78
Number: 343
Number: 3
```

But obviously my "FOR"-method is gibberish.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a fast enumeration `for` to do this. It iterates over all the keys in the dictionary:

```
for (NSString *key in dict) {
    double number = [[dict objectForKey:key] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"Number: %f", number);
}
```

Comment: That gives me "Sending "Double" to parameter of incompatible type "id""

Comment: @Luiz I think that the values ​​he has posted are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @JohnSmith I have made a correction on my code: changed the name of the key fom `number` to `key`, since `number` was conflicting with the `double` variable inside the loop.

Comment: @Mat You're right, the values are indeed strings, but he wants to print them formatted as floats using `NSLog`.

Answer (score 3):

Using blocks:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"5",   @"test1",
                            @"78",  @"test2",
                            @"343", @"test3",
                            @"3",   @"test4",
                            nil];

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Number: %@", obj);
}];
```

NSLog output:

```
Number: 5
Number: 3
Number: 343
Number: 78
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log these numbers, try the following:

```
for (NSString *number in dict) {
    NSLog(@"Number: %@",[dict objectForKey:number]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer has two objects being created with the name "number". Instead do:

```
for (NSString *key in dict) {
    NSLog(@"Number as double: %f", [[dict objectForKey:key] doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"Number as string: %@", [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

What's great about fast enumeration is that it creates the object for you (and auto-release them). The `key` is what's being given to you when fast-enumerating through NSDictionaries. Because you now have the key, you just grab the objectAtKey. In your case, it's a string in your dictionary, so you'll have to either convert it to a double (or whatever type you need), or output as a string. I added examples for both cases above. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned fast-enumeration is preferable in these cases, but you could also do something like this:

```
for (int i =0; i<[dict count]; i++){
        NSString *str=[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test%d",i+1]];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```